# How can I get HTTP request headers in Swift?

Tags: swift, http, curl, networking

I'm trying to get cookie and authorisation token that is being fetched at an endpoint

The curl command provided is:
curl 'url.com' -XGET -I

How can I fetch the request response in header in Swift?

I'm a newbie working with Swift networking and I've tried looking around on Stackoverflow but with no luck.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpurlresponse might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie myself, too. Let me try and help you.

```
func getCookiesAndAuthToken(_ url: URL?) {
    guard let url else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        // If error, exits the program
        guard error == nil else { print(error as Any); return }
        // typecast response to HTTPURLResponse so that we can access its property allHeaderFields a.k.a "headers"
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { print("could not typecast to HTTPURLResponse"); return }
        // typecast allHeaderFields to String: String Dictionary
        guard let fields = httpResponse.allHeaderFields as? [String: String] else { print("Error with headers"); return }
        // get your authorization token here
        // it probably is in the headers
        for (_, field) in fields.enumerated() {
            // ACTIONS REQUIRED FROM YOU:
            // do something here to match field's key so that you get the authorization token
            print(field)
        }
        // Space Between Token and Cookie infos
        for _ in 0...3 { print() }
        // get your cookies here
        let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: fields, for: (response?.url)!)
        // THESE ARE THE COOKIES THAT YOU WANT FROM THE WEBSITE THAT YOU VISITED ABOVE
        for cookie in cookies {
            print("name: \(cookie.name) value: \(cookie.value)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

## Edited

If you want a request-response like the Python Library requests, then, what's above is the answer. Perhaps, you need the request headers like below? Not sure, though.

```
func getCookiesAndAuthToken(_ url: URL?) {
    guard let url else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    guard let fields = request.allHTTPHeaderFields else { print("Error with headers"); return }
    // get your authorization token here
    // it probably is in the headers
    for (_, field) in fields.enumerated() {
        // ACTIONS REQUIRED FROM YOU:
        // do something here to match field's key so that you get the authorization token
        print(field)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this is helpful! Getting somewhere, appreciate all the comments in code to help me understand. // I'm getting all the data from response header, but the data I need is in the request header. Any idea how I can fetch them?